# How do I correctly manage the memory of dynamically allocated objects?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm building a program that will process some fake book orders, and I think I've run into a problem with how I am allocating my memory.

The program flow starts by opening up a text file with the information about each customer. I tokenize that information in a loop and create `Customer` objects that I want to insert into a database. Here is the loop I am using:

```
    while(fgets(stringBuf,100,dbFile))
    {

            string name(strtok(stringBuf,"|"));
            int custID = atoi(strtok(NULL,"|"));
            double credit = atof(strtok(NULL,"|"));
            string street(strtok(NULL,"|"));
            string state(strtok(NULL,"|"));
            string zip(strtok(NULL,"|"));


            Customer *newEntry = new Customer(name,custID,credit,street,state,zip);

            database.insert(newEntry);
    }
```

I use the `database` as a way to store the `Customer` objects, which get modified later on in the program. The point is that these `Customer` objects will be modified and will stick around in the database indefinitely until the end of the program. The problem arises when I try to clean up the memory allocated for these `Customers`. My `database` is set up as a sorted linked list, and this is the function I use to remove `Customers` from the `database`:

```
 void CustomerList::remove(int ID)
 {
    Customer *lead = this->getHead();
    Customer *tail = NULL;

    while(lead->getID() != ID) {
            tail = lead;
            lead = lead->getNext();
    }

    if(tail == NULL) { // means that lead is pointing to head
            this->setHead(lead->getNext());
            lead->setNext(NULL);
            delete lead;
            return;
    }
    else if(lead == NULL) { // element not found in the list        
            cout << "Element to be removed was not found in the list\n";
            return;
    }
    else {
            tail->setNext(lead->getNext());
            lead->setNext(NULL);
            delete lead;
            return;
 }
```

My concern is that I am not deleting the `Customer` objects correctly. I know that in C the exact pointer created by `malloc` needs to be given back to `free`, but I'm not sure if the same thing holds in C++ with `new` and `delete`. I allocated memory for the `Customer` in the original loop, but I try to return the memory using a method of another class. Is this a valid way to manage the memory, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?

Comment: Is there a reason to do things the hard way? Why not use an STL container (a sorted vector, sorted deque, sorted list, map, or unordered_map) or std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&, char delimiter) instead of fgets and strtok?

Comment: I guess I could have used those, but I wanted to try building everything from scratch to solidify my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `remove` function appears to be correctly deleting the `Customer` objects, if that's what you're asking about.  It doesn't correctly handle the case where the list is empty (i.e. `this->getHead()` returns `null`), though — it should check `lead` before trying to dereference it in the loop.

You're making things unnecessarily difficult for yourself by managing this linked list manually, however.  It'd be much simpler to store the newly-allocated `Customer` pointer in a `std::unique_ptr` (assuming you're using C++11) and then store that in a `std::list` or `std::vector`.  This will take care of automatically deleting the `Customer` when it's removed from the list (including when the entire list is destroyed).

BTW, the `lead->setNext(NULL)` in `remove` is unnecessary.  You're changing values in an object that's about to be deleted anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The rules in C++ are a little different: your program needs to make a call of either `delete` or `delete[]` operator, depending on the operator that you used to allocate the memory.

- If you used `new` to allocate memory for a single object, use `delete` operator
- If you used `new[]` to allocate memory for an array of objects, use `delete[]` operator

In your case you need to call `delete` (with no square brackets) on the instance of `Customer`. This should work fine, because all `Customer` objects are allocated in a loop and added to a non-shared container. Essentially, your linked list "owns" all your `Customer` objects. In cases like this, removing of a object from the list should trigger deallocation. In situations when your objects could be used from other places (i.e. the pointers are shared) removing an item from the list should not de-allocate the object.

Note: this is a very low-level of doing things. C++ library provides ready-made list containers, along with smart pointers that you could use for unique and for shared objects, which greatly simplifies the code.

Comment: Actually, the rules are exactly the same: Use the corresponding mechanism to dispose of any resource. Be that `delete`, `delete []`, `fclose`, `free` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Read about **RAII** - resource aquisition is initialization and use **smart pointers** they facilitate resources management (especially allocated memory)

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about using `delete` to free up memory allocated with `new`. I'm assuming that `database` is of type `CusttomerList`. In that case your code should work fine as long as you didn't accidentally `delete` or change any pointers in the list earlier. This is exactly why you should only use "naked `new`" when you absolutely have to. Instead, you can try `std::unique_ptr' in this case:

```
while(fgets(stringBuf,100,dbFile))
{

        // ...

        std::unique_ptr<Customer> newEntry
        { new Customer(name,custID,credit,street,state,zip)};

        database.insert(std::move(newEntry));
}
```

Of course you have to declare your list to be `list<unique_ptr<Customer>>` (assuming that you use the STL linked list. Then whenever you want to delete an element you call `element.reset()' and the memory is released automatically. One other advantage of this method is that you don't actually have to free up memory at all, since all unique pointers will automatically release the allocated memory whenever they go out of scope (e.g. by the end of the program). You should read more about smart pointers, because in most cases they make resource management more, well, manageable.

You might also want to put the following line in your `main()` to detect memory leaks:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
```